# AS3 Multiple instance names in one MC

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, multiple-instances

I apologize for how confusing this question is.

I have a Movie Clip that is a car.  In the car movie clip there are four different angles to the car.  (e.g. left, right, front back).   I dynamically change the body color of the car.  In each angle of the car, the body of the car has an instance name "body."  I change the color with the code :

```
var tempcar = "car_mc" + i;
var myNewTransform = new ColorTransform();
myNewTransform.color = 0x000000 //in real life this is a random value
this[tempcar].body.transform.colorTransform = myNewTransform;
```

Everything works fine, until I tell the car movie clip to gotoAndPlay the frame "front," where we see the front side of the car, and I try and apply the color change again to the body of the front of the car.  I get the error :

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
```

Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Since most of your application is on the timeline, why not also do the color transform on the timeline? Mixing timeline animations with ActionScript animations always brings lots of troubles.

Comment: do you have any scripts in the "front" movieclip?

Comment: There are no scripts in the Car movie clips.

Comment: I'm doing AS color changes because I'm spawning multiple instances off of a single library item and I want them to have different colors.

Answer (score 0):

That's the *old* ActionScript 2 way of handling things. In ActionScript the container is not always a MovieClip, which would except the hash to access a dynamic field. Also, if you'd added it to the display list via addChild, the result would be different as well, since it is not the case in ActionScript 3, that could address the child automatically.

You should use an Array to store and access dynamically created instances.

```
// clazz would be the symbol
function createInstance(container:DisplayObjectContainer, clazz:Class, list:Array):Sprite
{
  const child:MovieClip = new clazz() as MovieClip;
  if (!child) throw new ArgumentError("Wrong type given");

  return list[list.length] = container.addChild(child);
}

function getInstanceAt(index:int, list:Array):Sprite
{
  return list[index] as Sprite;
}
```